# Matlab Data: Remove negative values in a column?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data columns extracted using textscan from code shown below:

```
fid = fopen('wam1.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f','headerlines',4,'commentstyle','--');
fclose(fid);
x = C{1}; y1 = C{5}; y2 = C{3};
```

For major part of the column y1 & y2, I have negative value of -1, where no reading was taken.
My task is to substitute these -1 values in the columns with 0.

I tried using `changem` but I can't seem to get it working.

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a boolean vector of all elements that are -1 by `y1==-1` and substitute them for 0:

```
y2( y2 == -1 ) = 0
```